# strtok/strtok_r quit parsing in the middle

Tags: c, performance, tokenize, strtok

`strtok_r` puts null character into different places of the input string while parsing. The original string is restored only after `strtok_r` returns `NULL`.

What if I need to extract a token somewhere near the beginning of a long string? If I leave the loop, the input string remains broken. I could try to restore the delimiter manually, but I don't know whether it's the last token.
The problem is that `saveptr` value is not documented.

```
void extract_nth_token(char *res, size_t reslen, char *str, const char *delim, int n) {
  int i;
  char *token;
  char *save_ptr;

  token = strtok_r(str, delim, &save_ptr);
  for(i = 0; token != NULL; i++) {
    token = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &save_ptr);
    if (i == n) {
      snprintf(res, reslen, "%s", token);
      /* token[strlen(token)] = delim[0]; */
      /* break; */
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `The problem is that saveptr value is not documented.`   what kind of `value` you're looking for?

Comment: Make a copy of the string and use that.

Comment: @SouravGhosh the value to tell me whether it's the last token

Comment: @Barmar it's slower than finishing the loop

Comment: @basin How it will decide? You have the NULL return from `strtok()` to indicate the end but before reaching the end, there is no way the `saveptr` can be decided or marked as the last one.

Comment: @basin `save_ptr` is an opaque object, it's used to hold the internal state of the token parser. It has nothing to do with telling whether it's the last token.

Comment: I suspect you're making that assumption because the man page calls it `lasts`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh the doc could say: "`saveptr` is the pointer to the remaining string or NULL, if it was the last token". Then I could check this value and put the delimiter

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. IMHO the best way is to avoid strtok() and strtok_r(), and parse the string with a handmade stepper, maybe using strstr(), strchr() , strspn() and strcspn().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strtok() and strtok_r() are terrible functions:

- they modify the input string
- They treat consecutive delimiters as one, which may be intended when skipping whitespace, but which is not intended when parsing .CSV (or tab-separated) input.

Best is to avoid strtok() and strtok_r() completely, and use strspn() and strcspn(). The below function does that. The return value is similar to that of snprintf(): the number of characters in the found token (without counting the terminating NUL byte)

- if there is no token#n: '\0' is written to the buffer and 0 is returned
- if the buffer is too small for the found token plus the terminating NUL byte, '\0' is written to the buffer and the token length is returned
- is the buffer is large enough, the token + '\0' is written to it, and strlen(token) is returned.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t extract_nth_token_ohne_strtok_r(char *res, size_t maxlen, const char *str, const char *delim, int n)
{
size_t pos, len;
int itok;

for (itok=0,pos=0; str[pos]; ) {
        len = strcspn(str+pos, delim);
        if (itok++ == n) {
                if (len < maxlen) memcpy(res, str+pos, len), res[len] = 0;
                else res[0] = 0;
                return len;
                }
        pos += len;
        if (str[pos]) pos++;
        }
res[0] = 0;
return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
char * omg = "zero one\ttwo \tfour\nfive" ;
char token[80];
size_t toklen;
int ii;

printf("\n## With a large enough buffer:\n" );
for (ii=0; ii < 7; ii++) {
        toklen = extract_nth_token_ohne_strtok_r(token, sizeof token
                , omg, " \t\n", ii);
        printf("%d: res=%zu \"%s\"\n" , ii, toklen, token );
        }

printf("\n## With 4-character buffer:\n" );
for (ii=0; ii < 7; ii++) {
        toklen = extract_nth_token_ohne_strtok_r(token, 4
                , omg, " \t\n", ii);
        printf("%d: res=%zu \"%s\"\n" , ii, toklen, token );
        }

return 0;
}
```

---

Note: if you *do* want to treat consecutive whitspace as one, you could replace the `if (str[pos]) pos++;` by:

```
pos += strspn(str+pos, delim);
```